# How to return value to Promise chain from callback

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, bluebird

I am using another library (THREE.js) that uses single value callbacks for several of its loaders. I want to call them from within a Promise and pass the values down the chain.

I am already getting a promise from the previous method so I want to continue the chain. This gives me something like:

```js
var callStuff = (input, callback) => {
  // open some files and create some buffers
  // callback with buffer handles
  setTimeout(callback, 1000, input + 2);
};

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(1);
}).then(result => {
  callStuff(result, value => {
    console.log("callback:", value);
    return value;
  });
}).then(newResult => {
  console.log("newResult: ", newResult);
  return newResult;
});
```

Note that this is a simplified version so I can put it here.

How can I get the return value `newResult` from the callback?

I know that I can use something like [Bluebird's .asCallback][1], but then I have to `catch` to get the data that I want since the libraries don't use Node style callbacks. Is there any way to get the return value that I want?
Thanks!

UPDATE: I did find a workaround by wrapping the callback in a `new Promise` and then `resolve`ing inside the callback, but this feels like cheating. I'm hoping to find a better / more logical way if it's possible.

```js
var callStuff = (input, callback) => {
  // open some files and create some buffers
  // callback with buffer handles
  setTimeout(callback, 1000, input + 2);
};

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(1);
}).then(result => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    callStuff(result, value => {
      console.log("callback:", value);
      resolve( value );
    });
  });
}).then(newResult => {
  console.log("newResult: ", newResult);
  return newResult;
});
```

UPDATE 2: Just to clarify, I cannot edit the function that does the callback (calls back?) as it is a library and I'd rather dig through there code to make changes.

Comment: Make that `callStuff` return a promise instead of taking a callback. Wrapping it inside `new Promise` is exactly the way to go if you cannot edit its code - it's not cheating at all. Move it into a helper function if you don't like the look.

Comment: Would you mind throwing that in an answer with any references? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do a Return in your callback?

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(5);
}).then(result => {
  let retVal;
  return callStuff(value => {
    console.log(value + result);
    return retVal = value + result;
  }).then(() => retVal);
 
}).then(newResult => {
  console.log(newResult);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.0/bluebird.js"></script>
```

Comment: That worked, but when testing it out I found a small caveat that is my actual problem. What about when the callback doesn't `return callback`?

Comment: What does callStuff return? A Promise?

Comment: I updated the answer .Assuming callStuff  is synchronous (no promises) ,you could do this.Is this what you want?

Comment: callStuff is asynchronous, but it doesn't return callback, it only calls callback.

Comment: your example isn't indicative of the problem. In there callStuff is synchronous

Comment: Edited again. See if that suits you, or else update your question with a better code sample.